# MVim terminal, how to execute multiple commands

Tags: terminal, multiple-lines

I am trying to use MacVim's :terminal  to execute some commands, but for some reasons I fail to make even the simplest functions work.

Here are some examples:

```
    :function TryF()
    :   execute 'terminal ++rows=10 print "Hello"'
    :endfunction
```

gives me as output "executing job failed: No such file or directory".

```
    :function TryF()
    :   execute 'terminal ++rows=10 cd %:h && ls'
    :endfunction
```

gives me no output at all, while if I reverse:

```
    :function TryF()
    :   execute 'terminal ++rows=10 ls && cd %:h'
    :endfunction
```

I get a weird bunch of errors. I am using a macbook air. Any clues what might be going wrong?

BTW: If I pass only the command 'ls' to terminal I do not get any error.. I execute the functions from vim with :call TryF().

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `:term` the `++shell` option.

From `:help :term`:

> `++shell`: Instead of executing `{command}` directly, use a shell, like with `:!command`.

This should work:

```
function! TryF()
    terminal ++rows=10 ++shell cd %:h && ls
endfunction
```

Comment: Great! That does the trick, and it educated me on the difference between shell and terminal :)